# remove default gap between bootstrap spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using bootstrap for developing a responsive web page. It's good to use spans as like

```
class="span6", class="span3", class="span3"
```

for three different sections under a row element. It does the same what I need but in between there are some default spaces which looks ugly sometimes. Can I customize it to reduce the default space in between so that the elements may be a bit closer than the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the classes span#, you can remove the margin by setting `margin: 0`, but you won't get a fluid response when on the desktop or tablet view.

I suggest you upgrade to the newer Bootstrap 3 that uses the `col-sm-#` approach with padding, it's simpler to modify because removing of adding padding in no way affects responsiveness.